# Force Ubuntu 16.04 to reconfigure/reinstall Xenial packages

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

While upgrading from 14.04, my session was killed after I've locked my session near the very end of the upgrade, which caused my installation to be in some sort of half migrated state (some features are completely messed up, System Settings lead to a crash). Ubuntu thinks that it is already fully upgraded, which means that commands to trigger an upgrade do not work.

I've tried to run the xenial script in [xenial.tar.gz](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/), but I'm getting the following Python error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./xenial", line 3, in <module>
    from DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeMain import main
ImportError: No module named 'DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeMain'
```

Is there a different way to force Xenial to somewhat re-upgrade its packages?

Comment: You can try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a`; but it may not work and you may be faced with a reinstall

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, it does not do anything. I'll wait a bit before nuking the installation, but that might very well be the only option.

Comment: usually you try and set your system to a state where it won't be interrupted for the upgrade; this may sound counter-intuitive at some levels but it helps prevent things from getting busted by lockouts.  I suspect you have some things that're broken so therefore you're about out of luck.