# Failed upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 - "No module named DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeVersion"

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, python, 17.10, do-release-upgrade

In trying to upgrade my Ubuntu virtual server from 17.10 to 18.04.2 LTS:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Results in this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 8, in <module>
    from DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeVersion import VERSION
ImportError: No module named DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeVersion
```

This is the first import in that python script so I'm nervous that I've overlooked something fairly obvious about my python install. I checked the python link used in the do-resease-upgrade verison with:

```
head -n1 /usr/bin/do-release-upgrade
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Verifying that the do-release-upgrade point to the correct link:

```
sudo which do-release-upgrade
/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade
```

I have verified that I have a symbolic link in /usr/bin/ to python3

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          18 Mar 22 12:34 python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root   root     4568920 Oct  3  2017 python3.6
```

And should note that reinstalling python3 does not change the result. I've made no other changes to python recently.

If I run the command in python `/usr/bin/python3.6` the error generated changes from ImportError to ModuleNotFound as shown below:

```
>>> from DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeVersion import VERSION
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DistUpgrade'
```

I'm not familiar enough with this to know whether I should be searching for the DistUpgrade module to install or if there is another issue at play.

Reconfiguring the packages with `sudo dpkg --configure -a` also does not fix the problem.

I did take a look at [askubuntu.com/q/565107/301745](http://askubuntu.com/q/565107/301745) but was experiencing none of the other issues that the user was experiencing. Furthermore, I also have not attempted to remove any versions of python, as this user had. (Though, in my troubleshooting I did reinstall python3 and saw no change in behavior.)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the output of `head -n1 /usr/bin/do-release-upgrade`? Have you made any changes to your Python setup?

Comment: Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/q/565107/301745

Comment: Hmm. If you run `/usr/bin/python3.6` and do `from DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeVersion import VERSION`, does it succeed?

Comment: Ooh, that's a different error, `ImportError` vs `ModuleNotFoundError`. That might indicate that `sudo do-release-upgrade` is using Python 3.5 or lower. But just to confirm, did you run `/usr/bin/python3.6` exactly like I said?

Comment: Try `sudo which do-release-upgrade`

Comment: @wjandrea `type -a do-release-upgrade` results in `/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade` I'm not sure I understand fully where you're going with this. Now, if this is using an earlier version, does this mean installing a 3.5? I only have 3.6 and 2.7 installed on the server.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comments a few times. Try `sudo which do-release-upgrade` specifically. We need to make sure `sudo do-release-upgrade` calls `/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: No problem. `sudo which do-release-upgrade` results in: `/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade`

Comment: Based on the comments [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/760510/301745) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/775328/301745), you could try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, but double-check that before running it, cause I'm getting out of my depth.

Comment: @wjandrea No change in behavior after running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: I have resolved this issue by installing python 3.5 which resolves this issue. try this http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/07/install-python-3-6-1-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/

Hope it works for you. :)

Comment: After resolving this issue if you face "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading."

try this: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/troubleshooting-please-install-available-updates-release-upgrading/

Answer (score 2):

Solved: This issue is a python version issue, try to install python 3.6 which is minimum requirement to import the packages.

If this failed don't worry keep following all the steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
```

Then check updates and install Python 3.6 via commands:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

Now you have three Python versions, use python command for version 2.7, python3 for version 3.5, and/or python3.6 for version 3.6.1

To make python3 use the new installed python 3.6 instead of the default 3.5 release, run following 2 commands

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.5 1

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 2
```

Finally, switch between the two python versions for python3 via command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

After selecting version 3.6:

```
python3 -V
```

UPDATE: due to this bug, gnome-terminal won’t launch after step 3, a workaround is running following commands to recreate the symlink:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python3

sudo ln -s python3.5 /usr/bin/python3
```

Check this resource: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/07/install-python-3-6-1-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/

Now if you face another error like this:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

The Fix
If you experience the error above run each command below.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade -y

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Resource: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/troubleshooting-please-install-available-updates-release-upgrading/
Hope it help and resolve your issue too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, because I disabled the `snapd.service`. Check the snapd.service with the command :
`sudo systemctl status snapd.service`

If it's inactive:

> ● snapd.service - Snap Daemon
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
> Active: inactive (dead)

Start the service with `sudo systemctl start snapd.service` then start the release upgrade